# How identify disk scsi address on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, freenas

I'm using FreeNAS 9.3 , which is a FreeBSD 9.3 . 
This under vmware ESXi .

I have 3 disk, configured for this VM .

Need replace one disk for other (because physically it's failing).

Already add the new disk at the VM and it's already recognized by FreeNAS, but I not able to identify what disk I need to remove (because there are more than one with same size).

At linux, I'm capable to identify at /dev/disk/by-path , where I associate the SCSI address (eg.: 0:10) on linux with the VMWare configuration...

The commands `camcontrol devlist`, `pciconf`, `geom disk list`,  doesnt help.

Where I can get the SCSI address from specific disk?

Answer (score 3):

[camcontrol](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=camcontrol) it the proper tool for the purpose when using both ATA and SCSI disks. You even state you tried it - but not why you could not use it.

A typical output would be:

```
# camcontrol    devlist
  at scbus1 target 0 lun 0 (ada0,pass0)
  at scbus2 target 0 lun 0 (ada1,pass1)
  at scbus4 target 0 lun 0 (ada2,pass2)
  at scbus5 target 0 lun 0 (ada3,pass3)
```

Previously *(before FreeBSD 9)* there was separate tool for ATA disks named `atacontrol` - this has been replaced by `camcontrol`.

Comment: really... camcontrol show the information... and I have used this command before, but i don't "see" the information, just now notice is the same information of dmesg...

Comment: I don't know why I don't able to check any correct answer lately ...  sorry... give +1

Answer (score 1):

Just found one way...
A grep at dmesg.boot
where  scbus# is the SCSI ID and target # the address at this ID.

```
jdivm13# grep "da[0-9] at" /var/run/dmesg.boot
da0 at mpt0 bus 0 scbus2 target 0 lun 0
da1 at mpt1 bus 0 scbus3 target 1 lun 0
da2 at mpt1 bus 0 scbus3 target 2 lun 0
da3 at mpt1 bus 0 scbus3 target 3 lun 0
da4 at mpt1 bus 0 scbus3 target 4 lun 0
da5 at mpt2 bus 0 scbus4 target 1 lun 0
da6 at mpt2 bus 0 scbus4 target 2 lun 0
da7 at mpt2 bus 0 scbus4 target 3 lun 0
da8 at mpt2 bus 0 scbus4 target 4 lun 0
da9 at umass-sim0 bus 0 scbus6 target 0 lun 0
```